# Subsetting dataframe while using conditional statements and column names? What am I missing?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a new dataframe by extracting a column (EMO_ETA.3) for specific rows (zyg==1) from an original dataframe. I would like to write a piece of code that refers to this column by its name, not the index. Can someone help me understand why the bottom piece of code doesn't work and would be the correct way to do it?

```
new <- original[original$zyg==1][,c(3)] # works
new <- original[original$zyg==1][,c("EMO_ETA.3")] # doesn't work
```

```
    ID zyg EMO_ETA.3 ACT_ETA.3
1 2330   2    -2.693     2.359
2 2331   1    -1.029    -0.286
3 2333   1     0.203     0.938
4 2334   2    -0.853    -0.405
5 2336   1    -0.969    -2.122
6 2337   2    -0.956    -1.026
```

Comment: Neither of those should work.  It should be using `original[original$zyg==1, ]` to select the rows (note the comma).   So to subset by row and column use `original[original$zyg==1, "EMO_ETA.3"]`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use some functions from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
new <- original %>% filter(zyg == 1) %>% select(EMO_ETA.3)
```

As for the use of column names within brackets, I believe that generally it is best practice to use the numbered index, and that if referencing the column names, especially without a $ indicator, you would have to use functions such as those found within dplyr.

Comment: Understood. I'm trying to run a separate piece of code, summarise_all(complete_data_wide[complete_data_wide$zyg==1][,c("EMO_ETA.3")], .funs = funs(mean, sd), na.rm = TRUE), where I really want to use the column names instead of indexes. Would like to know how to do so.

Comment: It is best to provide a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're describing and you would probably want to repost as a new question with that reproducible example for that second problem.

Answer (score 0):

You first filter your data by row and you need adding comma after filtering for 'zyg' values. Then you want to filter variables and no need to add comma in this case. The resulting output is a df and not a vector. here is the code:

```
original[original$zyg==1,]['EMO_ETA.3']
```

hope thats what you are looking for.

Comment: put the variable names in a character vector: original[original$zyg==1,][c('EMO_ETA.3','ACT_ETA.3')]

Comment: Also, you don't need two pairs of brackets: `original[original$zyg==1, c('EMO_ETA.3','ACT_ETA.3')]`